# Does the Radon-Nikodym chain rule imply the usual chain rule?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, chain-rule

If I understand correctly, for signed measures $\nu,\mu$ and $\lambda$ on a common measurable space, if $\nu$ and $\mu$ have enough null sets, then $$\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} = \frac{d \nu}{d\mu}\frac{d \mu}{d\lambda},$$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere.

This looks suspiciously like the Leibniz chain rule, except that, well, the Leibniz chain rule doesn't make too much sense to me, whereas the above formula is perfectly clear. Anyway, I was wondering if its possible to recover the Langrange-notation version of the chain rule from single-variable calculus, namely $$(g \circ f)' = (g' \circ f) \cdot f',$$ from the above formula.

Comment: As an aside, IIRC, the Leibniz chain rule is basically the same thing as the R-N chain rule. More generally, if you have three things $u,v,w$ such that any can be written as a multiple of the other, then if we define $\frac{w}{u}$ to *mean* the ratio: that is, the quantity satisfying $w = \frac{w}{u} u$, then $\frac{w}{u} = \frac{w}{v} \frac{v}{u}$. In your example, the three things are the measures $\mu, \nu, \lambda$. In the Leibniz chain rule, they're the three differentials $\mathrm{d}x$, $\mathrm{d}y$, and $\mathrm{d}u$. (although, unfortunately, it's usually not phrased in these terms)

Comment: @Hurkyl, honestly I've never understood the differential form perspective on Leibniz's chain rule. For starters, I'm not quite sure how to divide differential forms.